# substituir todas as ocorrências de um caracter numa string com javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de substituir todas as ocorrências destes 2 caracteres  "_1" numa string por "_2", mas o Regex não aceita colocar lá uma variável.

```
var current_registration_number = 1;
html = html.replace(/\_{current_registration_number}/g, '_'+next_registration_number);
```

Alguém me ajuda a ultrapassar este problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não precisas de usar regex podes usar [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)/[`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) que separa a string por esse caracter e depois volta a juntar inserindo o novo caracter como união dessas partes:

```
html = html.split('_' + current_registration_number ).join('_' + next_registration_number);
```

Para usar regex tens de usar o construtor [`new RegExp();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\_' + current_registration_number, 'g');
html = html.replace(regex, '_' + next_registration_number);
```

repara que tens de usar duas vezes `\\` pois essa string que passas ao construtor "escapa-se" na conversão.